# With Pusher, is there a way to prevent people from abusing a service's event update channels?

Tags: pusher

For a startup considering making public notifications intended for website users available via a Pusher channel, how do you prevent people from subscribing to that channel for a long period of time (camping essentially)? I know you can disconnect users after a period of inactivity if they are connected from a web client (by checking for activity on the client and sending a disconnect after a period of inactivity), but what if users decide to connect via a command-line app or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Pusher provides [private channels](https://pusher.com/docs/private_channels) where the subscription to those channels need to be signed using your application secret in order for the subscription to be allowed.

Given the command-line app example you've provided the author of that application would not know the application secret and would therefore not be able to subscribe to the private channel.